# querying data from foreign key (specifically, UserProfile)

Tags: django, django-views

If I have a model with a couple of fields that inherit from a UserProfile model:

```
class LeaveRequest(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=False, null=False)
    submit_date = models.DateField(("submit date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    leave_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    start_date = models.DateField(("start date"))
    return_date = models.DateField(("return date"))
    ...
```

and I use this model to create a model form:

```
class LeaveRequestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = LeaveRequest
```

how can I query for the email url in the User Profile? In this view function, I'm trying to send a notification email on form submit, to the sender(employee) and supervisor:

```
def create_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LeaveRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['employee']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['leave_type']
            message = form.cleaned_data['notes']
            sender = form.cleaned_data['employee']

            remoterq = form.save(commit=False)
            remoterq.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            recipients = [user.email for user in remoterq.employee, user.email for user in remoterq.supervisor]
            from django.core.mail import send_mail
            send_mail(subject, message, 'projects.xxx@google.com', recipients, fail_silently=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('.')
```

my code for the "recipients" var is invalid but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
remoterq.employee.user.email
```

for the employee email and

```
remoterq.supervisor.user.email
```

for the supervisor email.